# Redis SLAVEOF for single database

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm hoping to run a `SLAVEOF` command from a new redis box to migrate data from an Elasticache node to a normal EC2 box running redis. Ideally I would run something like `SLAVEOF IP DB_INDEX` so that I'm only pulling data from `DB_INDEX` on the master instead of all available databases. Is this possible?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible. Look at the documentation for the [slaveof command](http://redis.io/commands/slaveof). PS: I replicated out of Elasticache to a redis server on a new EC2 instance before and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not replicate just a single "database" in Redis. It is easier to think of these as "keyspaces" rather than individual databases. Further, according to the documentation at Elasticache the way to import data is to upload a snapshot (RDB file) - not via a replication command.

Since you are just doing a migration you could:

1. Replicate to a clean instance
2. Iterate over all databases you don't want and do a `FLUSHDB` (do NOT do a `FLUSHALL`).
3. Then, if you want the data to be on DB0 and it is not there, you can use the [MOVE](http://redis.io/commands/move) command on each key to put it in the default 0 database.

This would result in having your new instance having just the data you want there, in the "0" database - if you chose to move the keys.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. We're actually going the other way (Elasticache -> EC2) so the SLAVEOF command makes things a bit easier in that we don't have to worry about carrying over the delta created during the migration. As per tobiash's comment above, it appears we can't do what we were hoping which to be honest isn't the end of the world

Comment: As long as you can issue slaveof to an EC2 instance, that covered item 1 in my answer. I apologize if that wasn't clear enough. I'm not sure why I left the part about going I to elastic ache in there. You will have a delta from the moment you commence step 2, of course. But given you can't replicate a single DB that is the best you can get I believe. It's one of the reasons I recommend avoidance of the select command.